# How to iterate through many GenServers of the same type?

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server

Problem: I have a type `FlyServer` and need to iterate through all the `Fly` processes. For various computations on the server.

How do I accomplish this?

One option is to have a GenServer list of all the FlyServer processes. But what if it crashes? And what if a player crashes and for whatever reason the GenServer keeping track of the processes isn't notified --- chime in if that scenario is unrealistic please.

Comment: What is your exact use-case? Have you considered using `Phoenix Presence`?

You can have processes register on it when they join.
Whenever a process leaves or joins you get a message with a diff of their metadata.

At any time you can query the list of active processes and set flags for them if necessary(to indicate that they are in different states for instance)

Comment: *How to iterate through many GenServers...?* -- Your title and your question don't seem to match.  Your question seems to indicate that you have one `gen_server`(FlyServer) and many client(Fly) processes.

Comment: What about using a supervisor to start them? and use supervisor:which_children/1 to iterate through them.

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to start your servers using a supervisor with a call to supervisor:start_child/2. The supervisor should use the strategy simple_one_for_one which is meant to create and supervise processes of the same kind.

Then you can get an updated list of all the chidren using the function supervisor:which_children/1

Answer (score 2):

1. Every time a Fly process contacts the server, you can add its pid to a list, where the list is part of the gen_server's State.
2. The server can then `monitor` the Fly process, which means that when a Fly process terminates, the  server will get sent a special message.
3. The server can implement a receive clause that pattern matches the special message and then removes the terminated process's pid from the list.

> One option is to have a GenServer list of all the FlyServer processes.
>   But what if it crashes?

Then `terminate(Reason, State)` will be called in the callback module, which can save State to an ets, dets, or mnesia table.  Of course, if someone trips over the cord that connects the server running the FlyServer to an electrical outlet, then execution will immediately halt and `terminate()` will not be called.  See `distributed erlang` for solutions.